# Insufficient funds for gas * price + value Etherum Wallet

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

`` Version: `0.11.1`
OS & Version: windows
Node version: `geth 1.8.13`
Number of blocks synchronized: 55
Private network ``

I am testing with Ethereum Wallet using the private test network created by geth. When trying to deploy a contract, after entering the password, a returned error occured: "insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

[image]

[image]
Anyone can help please !
Thanks you

Comment: Typically this is a problem of not being fully synchronized with the blockchain but if you're using a private chain then that probably isn't the issue.. But make sure you are synced up